# Figures ignores page break and sidesubfloat takes different room

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, sidesubfloat

additionally to my old thread a question I think anybody will struggle with if there are a lot pictures to show in comparison in an array- like structure.

Like before maybe some kind of overdefinition from variables may be the problem my -not so short, but short- preamble.

Here's the code, the example picture below. To define the problems.

```
\documentclass
[   draft=false,
fontsize=12pt,                  
parskip=half,                   
DIV=calc,                   
BCOR=17mm,                      
headsepline,                
footsepline,                
open=right,                 
paper=A4,      
appendixprefix=true,        
abstract=true,              
listof=totoc,               
bibliography=totoc,             
titlepage=true,             
headinclude=true,               
footinclude=false,              
numbers=noenddot,               
oneside,
openany                         
]   {scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames}{xcolor}
\usepackage[usenames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\mylanguage}{american,ngerman}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\KOMAoptions{float=true}
\usepackage[\mylanguage]{babel}     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         % Zeichencodierung nach UTF-8 (Unicode)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{url}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=large, labelfont=sf,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage[format=plain,
%justification=centerlast,
indention=0.5cm, %die indention ist ok lass mer so!
singlelinecheck=true, %false makes much more errors !!!
labelfont=bf,
%width=\textwidth,
aboveskip=10pt,
belowskip=0pt,
textfont=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{units}

\pdfcompresslevel=9             

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{libertine}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\invisiblecomment}[1]{\ignorespaces} %for comments

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, bottom=3.5cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead[]{\pagemark}
\chead[]{}
\ifoot[]{}
\ofoot[]{\scriptsize Hello}
\cfoot[]{}

%% ========================================================================
%%%% begin{document}
%% ========================================================================
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\   
    \newpage %no affect
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\

    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill%
    \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.445\textwidth]{example-image-b}}\\
    \caption{An array of twelve (6x2) figures} %this disappears... but shouldn't
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here the picture, with notes:
[image]